# rewrite google custom search string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

My previous custom google search appeared this how:

(first link) http:/raskim.lt/controller/function/**music?cx=014092587915392242087%3Agc6l6xlpkmq&cof=FORID%3A11&q=this%is%example&sa=Search**

I change my Google CSE script. Now im usign jsapi. My new search generates:

(second link) http:/raskim.lt/controller/function/music?**q=this%is%example**

How to rewrite url that if someone visit first link, would be redirected to second link?

Now my .htaccess looks:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on


#AllowOverride All
#RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.raskim\.lt$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.raskim.lt/$1 [L,R=301]
# Restrict your site to only one domain
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/music)$ $1?q=%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: after adding this code to my .htaccess im getting this in my url
http://www.raskim.lt/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/home/yeylt/domains/raskim.lt/public_html/controller/function/music?q=this+is+example

I think it is becouse of my others RewriteRules

Comment: Update your qn with your current htaccess code. Are there any other rules present?

Comment: Yes. these-
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
 RewriteEngine on

 
 #AllowOverride All
 #RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.raskim\.lt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.raskim.lt/$1 [L,R=301]
 # Restrict your site to only one domain
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>`

Comment: You have your `RewriteBase` commented out with `#`. Can you enable and then try? If it doesn't work, also try `/$1` with rewrite base on and off.

Comment: According to Ravi Thapliyal I enabled this line

    #RewriteBase /

And now my problem is solved. rewriting is working

Comment: Maybe you know how to disable encoding on this rewrite rule? Becouse my query string includes charachters like ĮŠŲ.. and they are converting to %20 and so on. This effects to no results on search

Comment: If your PHP is receiving encoded characters try adding `[NE]` to the rule. `[R=301,NE,NC,L]` would enable `No Escape` for your rewrite rule.