# Google Custom Search: Rewrite urls

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-custom-search

I have a little difficulty understanding, why in the world doesn't Google Custom Search accept my search query, which is rewritten using .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

The problem is very trivial: I have a WordPress installation where I have a static page (ID of which is 12) dedicated to search results from Google CSE, which takes and argument 'q' from address bar ($_GET ...) as a search query. And it works beautifuly. Ex.:

```
http://example.com/?page_id=12&q=cars
```

Google CSE return whatever it could find on 'cars'. Perfect.

But if I make a trivial rewrite rule in my .htaccess file, which goes like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) index.php?page_id=12&q=$1 [L]
```

it does not accept the 'q' argument. Other scripts do accept it just fine (I have a script that changes a title of a page according to whatever the user is searching for). It is quite important for me to have SEO urls, as it is prettier and more useful for a user to see.

Has anyone bumped into this kind of problem? Thank you for any useful answers.

Comment: You might find this a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208131/rewrite-google-custom-search-string)